# How to select visitor counts by days

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have this table from which I need to select visitors count by date.

```
CREATE TABLE `visitors` (
  `id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ip` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  `browser` VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
  `version` VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
  `platform` ENUM('w','l','m') NOT NULL,
  `date` DATE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `person` (`ip`,`date`)
) ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**I try this:**

```
SELECT DATE(`date`) AS `date`, COUNT(*) AS `visitor`
FROM `visitors` WHERE (`date` >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY))
GROUP BY `date`;
```

**Which returns this:**

```
date         visitor
2015-12-19    2
2015-12-22    5
```

**But what I really want is this:**

```
date         visitor
2015-12-17    0        // Make 0 for the day which is not present
2015-12-17    0        // Make 0 for the day which is not present
2015-12-18    0        // Make 0 for the day which is not present
2015-12-19    2
2015-12-20    0        // Make 0 for the day which is not present
2015-12-21    0        // Make 0 for the day which is not present
2015-12-22    5
```

If I try with unions and get dates with this it is not problem with example 1 week. But what can I do if I need 1 year?

Comment: Sounds like you need a calendar table.

Comment: I do not think that it is good idea to create 1 table with dates...
it need a lot of memory...
I need 0 if it is not presents in table...
this is only problem.

Comment: @maiabardavelidze sql cannot invent what is not there, so you **will need** some kind of a helper table. See the duplicate topic I linked above.

Comment: @maiabardavelidze A table holding all necessary dates is a depressingly small thing.

Comment: @Strawberry you do not even need a calendar table, just a table that holds numbers 1 to 7, just as the linked topic describes

Comment: The date datatype requires 3 bytes of storage, this equates to 13kB per 100 years. I **really** don't think storage space will be an issue with a calendar table.

Comment: @Shadow You don't even need that ;-)

Comment: ok. so please tell me how to create calendar table and select this kind information from them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the sequence Engine. So you can generate date without a table

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/sequence/

```
MariaDB [mysql]> SELECT date(now() - INTERVAL seq DAY) FROM seq_0_to_6;
+--------------------------------+
| date(now() - INTERVAL seq DAY) |
+--------------------------------+
| 2015-12-22                     |
| 2015-12-21                     |
| 2015-12-20                     |
| 2015-12-19                     |
| 2015-12-18                     |
| 2015-12-17                     |
| 2015-12-16                     |
+--------------------------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This will work without a other Engine. You only must have a table with more Records as Days. The count of Days backwards is the LIMIT.

```
SELECT compare_date , count(v.`date`)
FROM (
    SELECT DATE(now() - INTERVAL @nr:=@nr+1 DAY)  AS compare_date 
    FROM information_schema.COLUMNS, (SELECT @nr:=-1) AS tmp 
    LIMIT 7
    ) AS d
LEFT JOIN  `visitors` v ON v.`date` = compare_date
GROUP BY compare_date;
```

Please tell this works for you.

Comment: it is not working for me

Comment: I do not understand how to use DATE_ADD in my case. can anyone help me??? I think it may help...

Comment: @maia bardavelidze - I have add a other Query in at my answer. please test it.

Comment: yes it is working now.
and the last question.
how can I do like this on monthes and years?
example if I need year information
I must get last monthes count from january
and if I need all information
I must get the years visits count...

how can I do this?